# How to make the axes physically properly clip through a sphere?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have only seen questions where people wanted the axis to be overlaid on top of the plot. I want to do something more advanced. I want the axes to be rendered behind where you would expect them to be inside the surface, and rendered in front where you would expect them to be outside the surface.

The first image is what I currently have.

The second image is approximately what I would like to have. (apologies for the poor paint edit)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=center, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20, enlarge x limits={abs=27pt}, enlarge y limits={abs=13.3pt}, enlarge z limits={abs=10pt}]
%sphere
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp ,colormap={custom}{rgb255=(200,200,200)rgb255=(200,200,200)}, opacity=0.5, z buffer = sort, samples = 50,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:180, y domain = 0:360] ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {2*cos(v)});
%viviani cylinder parts
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={grayslate}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(200,200,200)}, opacity=0.5, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = -2:0, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {max(-sqrt(2*(2-x)),v)});
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={grayslate}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(200,200,200)}, opacity=0.5, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = 0:2, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {min(sqrt(2*(2-x)),v)});
%viviani window edge
    \addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, thick, black]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%equator
    \addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, dotted, black, line width=0.5pt]({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))},{0});
%equator cylinder
    \addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=30, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, thick, black]({1-cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way: compute the intersection between the Viviani curve and a path that runs along the z axis, and use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=center, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20, enlarge x limits={abs=27pt}, enlarge y limits={abs=13.3pt}, enlarge z limits={abs=10pt}]
%sphere
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp ,colormap={custom}{rgb255=(200,200,200)rgb255=(200,200,200)}, opacity=0.5, z buffer = sort, samples = 50,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:180, y domain = 0:360] ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {2*cos(v)});
%viviani cylinder parts
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={grayslate}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(200,200,200)}, opacity=0.5, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = -2:0, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {max(-sqrt(2*(2-x)),v)});
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={grayslate}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(200,200,200)}, opacity=0.5, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = 0:2, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {min(sqrt(2*(2-x)),v)});
%viviani window edge
    \addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, thick,
    name path=viviani,black]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%equator
    \addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, dotted, black, line width=0.5pt]({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))},{0});
%equator cylinder
    \addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=30, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, thick, black]({1-cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
    \path[name path=z-axis] (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:0,0,2);
    \draw[name intersections={of=z-axis and viviani}] (intersection-1) --
    ++(0,9pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, though, that there are some glitches if one increases the version number to, say, 1.16. Most likely they come from using `x` in the 3d plot, in which the variables are `u` and `v`. On the long run you may be better off if you changed the plots to another parametrization (such as the one of my previous answer).

Comment: I recall having to stay on a lower version due to something else I was working on, so I will not be running into that glitch unless I require something from a more recent update :)